# Hibernate opening session twice and transaction required

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, session, transactions

First of all I want to apologize if there is something related to my question in this site. I could not find anything.
I am developing a spring+hibernate app linked to front end written in AngularJS.
When I invoke specific action from the front end for example:

```
@MessageMapping("/markVoicemailAsRead/{uniqueId}")
public void markRead(@DestinationVariable int uniqueId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        voiceMailDao.setVoiceMailRead(uniqueId);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

everything is great and it works properly with my postgres db. The thing I found  weird is that in the `setVoiceMailRead(uniqueId)` I had to open another session and also I needed a transaction object. This is the implementation of the `setVoiceMailRead(uniqueId)`:

```
    public void setVoiceMailRead(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Query query = session.createQuery("update VoiceMail set read = :read"
            + " where uniqueId = :id");
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        query.setParameter("read", true);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

If I remove the session ant transaction in the markRead action I get error in the console "No active transaction" so I left it this way. I believe there is something wrong with my `hibernate.xml` file and the `<property>` tag:

`<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            </props>
        </property>`

Thank you in advance for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

In the first class no need to open session object and commit the transaction, Just class the method

setVoiceMailRead(uniqueId) in your markRead(-) method.

Comment: Thank you! As I said if I do this I receive the error: No active transaction :(

Answer (score 0):

While JPA doesn't require a transaction for read operations (falling back to auto-commit), all [write operations require a transaction](http://java.boot.by/scbcd5-guide/ch06.html):

> The persist, merge, remove, and refresh methods MUST be invoked
>   within a transaction context when an entity manager with a
>   transaction-scoped persistence context is used. If there is no
>   transaction context, the
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException is thrown.
>
> The find and getReference methods are NOT required to be invoked
>   within a transaction context. If an entity manager with
>   transaction-scoped persistence context is in use, the resulting
>   entities will be DETACHED; if an entity manager with an extended
>   persistence context is used, they will be MANAGED.

In `setVoiceMailRead` you need to call:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

to get the same Hibernate Session you opened in the root method. And you can only close in the root method instead.

Comment: I did it and unfortunately this error appeared: 
`createQuery is not valid without active transaction
 at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)`

Comment: The `thread` session context should allow you to reuse the same Session which should register the root transaction. You'll need to debug it in Hibernate code.